# methods to do a web conference Camera and microphone for ipad, android as a web based solution

Tags: android, ios, websocket, video-streaming, red5

I am currently building a virtual class room and I need to stream the camera and microphone to many students.

Previously I used red5 server, but due to the lack in the support for ipad, iphone and android, had to remove red5. I have abandoned webrtc since it is a peer to peer solution (Due to bandwith problems in client side).

The solution I am looking for is a web based solution and a non peer to peer solution is the preference. Is there a way to accomplish my task?  I'd like to do this as an open source project. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option may be to reexamine the webrtc route. You don't have to do peer-to-peer, you could in fact use your server to relay the streams. I can't think of any servers that do this off the top of my head, but I am certain that I've seen them while doing my research.